# Applying regular expressions to SQL databases in R

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, teradata, dbplyr

```
tbl(db_name, "table_name")
tbl(db_name, "table_name") %>% show_query()
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT *
#> FROM "table_name"
```

I can use the dplyr `tbl()` function on a database, and table without issue. When I invoke the `show_query()` function I can see that `tbl()` is performing a simple SQL query in the background. This is shown above.

What's shown below is the error I get when I try and apply a regular expression and mutate a column utilizing dplyr and R (maybe dbplyr too?). FYI this is being performed in a Teradata data warehouse.

```
tbl(db_name, "table_name") %>% 
  mutate(col1 = gsub("^0+(?!$)", "", col1))
#> Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
#>  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1000: 22800: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]
#>  [Teradata Database](-8607)Syntax error: expected something between '(' and 
#>  the string '^0+(?!$)'.
```

If I `show_query()` you can see how the `gsub()` is applied, which I'm guessing is improper syntax for SQL.

```
tbl(db_name, "table_name") %>% 
  mutate(col1 = gsub("^0+(?!$)", "", col1)) %>% 
  show_query()
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT "Plant_Material_Id", 
#>        "Plant_Id_In_Source", 
#>        gsub('^0+(?!$)', '', "col1") AS "col1", 
#>                                        "col2",
#>                                        "col3"        
#>                                              
#> FROM "table_name"
```

How can I mutate a column utilizing regular expressions in R, on a SQL database (specifically Teradata in this case)?

I should also mention I want to do this without utilizing the `collect()` function, because I want everything done on the server side. I'm working with (relatively) large databases and loading everything into memory isn't that practical.

Comment: Dbplyr doesn't have glob translation see https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/translation-function.html#unknown-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use SQL function `REGEXP_REPLACE()` instead of r function `gsub()`

```
tbl(db_name, "table_name") %>% 
  mutate(col1 = REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, "^0+(?!$)", "" ))
```

For PostgreSQL database just 'REPLACE`

Comment: is `asset_title` simply referring to the column I want to replace? If so, I tried that but get the same `expected something between ',' and the 'replace' keyword` type error. Maybe the syntax works on PostgreSQL but not Teradata SQL?

Comment: yes, you need your column name, not `asset_title`, fixed

Comment: you nee REGEXP_REPLACE for Teradata
https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/aohu2GV5DgPH0R5jQKr2HQ